# Direct sum of two spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $\alpha_1=[1,1,0,1]$, $\alpha_2=[1,0,1,1], \alpha_3=[1,1,1,1],\alpha_4=[0,1,1,1]$ be a vectors from $\mathbb{R}^4$ let $U=span(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \ and \ W=span(\alpha_3, \alpha_4)$ Check that $U\bigoplus W =\mathbb{R}^4$.
How to check that?

Comment: You can show both inclusions, namely $U \oplus W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ and $U \oplus W \supseteq \mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I know that but i do not know how to show that precisely

Comment: Consider the basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and see if you can express the basis of $U \oplus W$ in terms of it and vice versa.

Comment: Another possibility would be to show that $U+W=\mathbb{R}^4$ and $U\cap W = \{0\}$. First express arbitrary $v\in \mathbb{R}^4$ in terms of elements from $U$ and $W$, then show that no nonzero vector is in their intersection.

Comment: thanks, appreciate your help